# Cleaning up speckles around text in a scanned image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I've tried -noise radius and -noise geometry and they don't seem to do what I want at all. I have some b&w images (TIFF G4 Fax compression) with lots of noise around the characters. This noise takes the form of pixel blobs that are 1 pixel wide in most cases.

My desire is to do the following 3 steps (in this order):

1. Whiteout all black pixels that are 1 pixel wide (white pixels to the left and right)
2. Whiteout all black pixels that are 1 pixel tall (white pixels above and below)
3. Whiteout all black pixels that are 1 pixel wide (white pixels to the left and right)

Do I have to write code to do this, or can Imagemagick pull it off?  If it can, how do you specify the geometry to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking a lot of good answers here, I put this one to the ImageMagick forum and their response was really good.  You can read it here [ImageMagick Forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18707&sid=1df7c42b8e986dfa1b73d43467a62867)

Morphology proved to be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Blur then sharpen would be the normal technique for speckle noise.

Imagemagik can do both of these - you might have to play with the amoutn of blurring